# Event Rate Timing - Events/time period and real-time

Tags: python

I need to create various rate timers of events across a timed period.  For example, 5 events/16 seconds, or real-time.  Akin to bandwidth calculations.

From what I can tell, this is something that would need to be written from scratch, as the timing functions I've seen are for performing an event every X seconds.

Questions:

1. Are there libraries for this type of thing, or would they need to be written from scratch?
2. I have a fair stab at some manual functions, for example for events over time_len:

```
    def time( self,quantity ):

        self.this_ts = c.time.time_ns()

        self.this_diff_ts = self.this_ts - self.last_ts

        if( self.this_diff_ts < self.time_len ):
            self.this_count += quantity
        else:
            self.this_rate = self.this_count
            self.this_count = quantity
            self.ticks = 0

            self.last_ts = self.this_ts
```

Is that a reasonable approach?

3. How is a real-time rate actually calculated?  Would it be a count of events within a second averaged over seconds?

Thank you,

John

Comment: What is `self.time_len`?

Comment: `self.last_ts = self.this_ts` is unreasonable. You have no idea what might execute between this event and the next time you want to invoke new timing, but your start time is now fixed at this point for your next go. You need to show your class

Comment: self.time_len is the time internal, for example 2 seconds (converted to nanoseconds).  That's the only method in the class right now.  time() is called either via an event from a websocket or over USB (in progress).

Comment: And to clarify, the self.last_ts = self.this_ts is bad because it's not real-time, i.e., if an event takes longer than self.time_len?  That's the tricky part I can't figure out, if I'm understanding correctly.